"jim.log()" is not a function
function extend<T, U>(first: T, second: U): T & U {
  let result = <T & U>Object.assign({}, first, second);
  return result;
}

class Person {
  constructor(public name: string) { }
}
interface Loggable {
  log(): void;
}
class ConsoleLogger implements Loggable {
  log() {
    console.log("11")
  }
}
var jim = extend(new Person("Jim"), new ConsoleLogger());
console.log(jim);

var n = jim.name;
jim.log();

Why does this code give an error saying 'jim.log is not a function'? I checked and jim only has a name property. Why isn't the log function assigned to the jim object?

Object.assign takes only own properties and log() is not own - it's a prototype property. Nothing to do with TS, just base JS.

So how should I put the log into jim?

Please don't ask follow up questions in the comments. You can edit your question or ask a new question.
